# Meteor: Is there a way to intercept all server calls, sevrside?

Tags: meteor

I'd like a way to do some very generic stuff before server calls are executed.  Is there some callback I can use?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use a middleware ( https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html ). The documentation is not very exhaustive, but it's based on connect ( https://github.com/senchalabs/connect )